# how do i lock a row in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just created a slider that holds four images, the issue is, as soon as the pixel size dips below < 768px, the images begin to lose quality and then stack. Is there any possible way I can lock the images on one row so that they don't move after it goes below 768px?

Thanks in advance.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <!-- slider 1 -->
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                        <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                        <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                        <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                        <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!-- slider 2 -->
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                            <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                            <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                            <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                            <span><img class="d-block img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="images/5.jpg" alt="First slide"> </span>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.carousel-item span img {
     height:200px !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap 4, you have a new `col-` tag

So you need to use `col-3` in place of specifying `col-xs-3` for your divs
(Note that specifying `col-` automatically sets sm, xs, lg to the same widths unless you specify another class for sm/xs/lg)

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as6md81b/16/

Refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/